# Flutter: Unable or change the sensibility of the slide between the tabs of a TabController

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TabController with two tabs. Both of them with a List view (scrollable).

The problem is the sensibility needed to slide between tabs. If the user scroll a little bit in an angle and not vertically, the code thinks he wants to change tabs..

I am trying to whether remove the possibility to slide between tabs or change the sensibility of it.

Here is my current Tabbar.

```
return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        TabBar(
          controller: _nestedTabController,
          indicatorColor: kHighlightColor,
          labelColor: kHighlightColor,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(
              text: "Upload",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Favorite",
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          height: screenHeight * 0.75,
          child: TabBarView(
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            controller: _nestedTabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(child: Profile()), //ListView
              Container(child: Favorite()), //ListView
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Maybe I should change the physics of the TabBarView ?
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just had to change the physic method:

```
child: TabBarView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

And the swipe between tabs is unable.